# Has anyone seen this NPE in Oracle JDBC driver?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, ojdbc

We are going to be tracing the driver soon probably, but I wonder if someone has seen this. Some (3rd-party-library) code performs `rs.next()` on a resultset obtained from Oracle JDBC driver, and then calls `rs.getLong()` to get a `long` from a `NUMBER` column. All of this was working just fine for variety of versions of Oracle, JDBC, OSes, etc. for years, but on a particular machine, with Oracle 12.1.0.2 and ojdbc7 jar for that exact version (12.1.0.2, from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/default-2280470.html), the following exception happens:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DynamicByteArray.get(DynamicByteArray.java:350)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.NumberCommonAccessor.getLong(NumberCommonAccessor.java:546)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedStatement.getLong(GeneratedStatement.java:228)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedScrollableResultSet.getLong(GeneratedScrollableResultSet.java:564)
```

Unfortunately ojdbc is not open source. 
Is this a known issue?
Is there some alternative jdbc driver to try?

Comment: Cannot read Chinese, but same exception is also mentioned at http://f.dataguru.cn/thread-315841-1-1.html

Comment: This seems more a problem in the specific JVM than the driver. What JVM (vendor, version, build) at what operating system (vendor, version, build) are you operating on? Especially as you see it happen only on one specific machine (guess you tested it on others and couldn't reproduce there) it's almost certainly something that's specific to that machine (of course it could also be data, in which case you would get the same with the exact same data on another machine).

Answer (score 1):

Which version of the Oracle JDBC thin driver are you using? There was a bug that produced an exception similar to yours in version 12.1.0.1. It was fixed in 12.1.0.2. So it looks like an upgrade of your driver might resolve your problem.